# como acceder a los datos de mi json

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic

Me gustaría acceder al id del objeto usuarios pero no lo consigo

```
  {
         "supervisores":[
             {
                 "supervisorId":1,
                 "supervisorNombre":"nombre1",
                 "supervsiorApellidos":"apellidos1",
                 "usuarios": [
                     {
                         "usuarioId":1,
                         "usuarioNombre":"nombre1"
                     }
                 ]
             },
               {
                 "supervisorId":2,
                 "supervisorNombre":"nombre2",
                 "supervsiorApellidos":"apellidos2",
                 "usuarios": [
                     {
                         "usuarioId":2,
                         "usuarioNombre":"apellido2"
                     }
                 ]
             }
    
         ]
    }
```

Lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
 this.servicioService.getDatos()
      .subscribe((resp: any) => {
        console.log(resp.supervisores.usuarios);
        
        
      })
```

Al intentar acceder a usuarios me aparece undefined. He conseguido los datos del supervisor de la siguiente manera: resp.supervisores, pero al hacer un resp.supervisores.usuarios me aparece undefined. Alguien me puede orientar un poco. Gracias

Comment: `resp.supervisores[numerosupervisor].usuarios` Tienes que tener en cuenta que en ese json tienes dos supervisores, asi que es una array, si no le señalas a que posición acceder te saltará undefined

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que no estás indicando a los usuarios de qué supervisor quieres acceder. Si te fijas `supervisores` es un array de varios objetos. Para entonces poder acceder a uno en concreto (el primero por ejemplo) deberás acceder a la posicion del mismo de esta forma:

```
resp.supervisores[0].usuarios
```

en caso contrario, si quieres acceder a todos y cada uno de los usuarios de cada supervisor deberás recorrer el array de supervisores:

```
resp.supervisores.forEach(supervisor=>{
   supervisor.usuarios //este valor dentro es el valor del array de usuarios de cada supervisor
})
```